Form Validation message for Password Confirmation Field
I have below code in forms.py file.
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User        
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','date_of_birth', 'gender', 'user_type', 'phone', 'address','photo', 'password' )
        error_messages = {
            field: {
                'required': f"{field.replace('_', ' ').title()} is required."
            }
            for field in fields
        }

I would like to add 'password_confirmation' field in fields tuple.
I would like to use Form validation message like below in my HTML template.
<label class="form-label">PassWord Confirmation</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" />                                
{% if form.confirm_password.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ form.confirm_password.errors }}</div>
{% endif %}

But I am getting errors django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) () specified for User.

Django's UserCreationForm expects a password1 and password2 for password and password confirmation respectively. UserCreationForm already includes validation to ensure these 2 match.
Do not add password_confirmation to your fields tuple. Instead use password1 and password2 fields that are already included in UserCreationForm.
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','date_of_birth', 'gender', 'user_type', 'phone', 'address','photo')
        error_messages = {
            fields: {
                'required': f"{field.replace('_', ' ').title()} is required."
            }
            for field in fields
        }

In the HTML template, use password2 for the password confirmation field:
<label class="form-label">PassWord Confirmation</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" />                                
{% if form.password2.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ form.password2.errors }}</div>
{% endif %}

   


Thanks @Laszio Hunyadi. If I use <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ form.password2.errors }}</div> I am getting error message This field is required.. But I would like to get error message Password Confirmation is required.. Thanks.

@abuabu You can customize the error message for password2 in your CustomUserCreationForm by adding an entry for password2 in the error_messages dictionary.

Thanks @Laszlo Hunyadi. Could you please share some sample code ? Thanks.

Create a new post and @me.
